# Countdown from 60 to 0 in javascript and loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, timer

As some of you guys may know, I am still developing my game LOL.

Right now I have basic functionality. Players can see their profits display and buy stuff if they have enough money.

All i need now is to display how quick players are getting money. So players are supposed to have money generated every 60 seconds. The money gets generated but it has no visuals.

What i want is for people to see how much to they have left before they get the next money.[image]

so i have all the styling and that done for the timer. What i want is some vanilla javascript code to display the innerHTML for the time decrementing from 60 down to 0;

I have tried intervals with if statements and switch cases and ive tried a for loop but i cant get it to reset or even do anything.

Below is some of my code.

Code:

```js
// Income Ticker Display (displaying time until next pay day)
var incomeTicker = 60;

window.setInterval(function(){
 if (incomeTicker > 0)
  incomeTicker--;
      document.getElementById("incomeTicker").innerHTML = "Next Profit In : " + incomeTicker + " seconds";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span class = "incomeTicker" id = "incomeTicker" > Next Profit In : 60 seconds </span>
```

i have tried different ways of doing this and have looked a few questions but nothing is giving me what i need.

Thanks for any advise in advance.

ps. let me know if you need more code examples.

Comment: _“I have tried intervals with if statements and switch cases and ive tried a for loop but i cant get it to reset or even do anything.”_ Great! Now show that code. Show your work. And please use [formatted code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212) for it, _not pictures_.

Comment: please post what you have tried

Comment: Yeah Sorry i forgot - SO i added the javascript that i have but it is not affecting the DOM

Comment: @CorneliusLabuschagne Again: include all of your code as text and format it. Please see [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4642212).

Comment: Okay will replace PNG images with text now sorry i forgot not to do that lol please dont kill me

Comment: @CorneliusLabuschagne code updated. it is work

Comment: Thank you @BehnamMohammadi I am going to try it now. If it work then i mention you in the credits :)

Comment: I have made this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/bb9cjbmz/8/) for you, check it please.

Comment: Such a small thing i missed LOL i feel so stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKAY I FIXED MY LOOPING ISSUE AS WELL

```js
// Income Ticker Display (displaying time until next pay day)
var incomeTicker = 60;

window.setInterval(function(){
 if (incomeTicker > 0)
  incomeTicker--;
      document.getElementById("incomeTicker").innerHTML = "Next Profit In : " + incomeTicker + " seconds";
if (incomeTicker <= 0)
 incomeTicker = 60;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span class = "incomeTicker" id = "incomeTicker" > Next Profit In : 60 seconds </span>
```

Thank you every one for helping me solve this problem

Comment: Btw setInterval will work every second care second parameter of it.